# Access a vector inside of a map that is inside another map

Tags: c++, vector, maps

I have a map called nfa (see below)

```
map<string, NFANode*> nfa;
```

nfa is filled with NFANode objects. (see below)

```
class NFANode {
public:
   string label;
   map<string,vector<NFANode*> >tr;
   bool accepting;
   bool starting;
   NFANode(string s, bool a, bool x){
       accepting = a;
       label = s;
       starting = x;
   }

};
```

Inside each object there is another map call tr and inside of tr there is a vector with information. I am trying to access the vector to print out each element of the vector and cannot figure out how. I have been trying to use an iterator with no luck.

```
map<string, NFANode*>::iterator nfaIt;
for (nfaIt = nfa.begin(); nfaIt != nfa.end(); ++nfaIt){
    cout << "content of tr are: " << nfaIt->second->tr->second << endl;

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `nfaIt->second->tr` gets you to the inner map of `NFANode` in your outer-node in your outer-map. What do you plan on doing from there? dumping the label ? If ever there was a class screaming out for an `ostream` inserter override this is it. (and smart pointers, but one step at a time).

Comment: `tr` is a map, it's not an iterator

Comment: @billz could call. I missed that. the comment about a stream inserter stands, however. Nice catch.

Comment: You guys lost me, this is one of the first things I've done in c++ and my head is kind of swimming. I am really just trying to print the contents of tr to the console to make sure I have the right data inserted.

Comment: @TimHorner this is a "nested" container, right? Your global map `nfr` maps strings to a vector of `NFANode` pointers, each of which can have a map of strings to a vector of `NFANode` pointers, each of which... etc. Assuming you don't stuff a "parent" pointer inside a "child"'s map (i.e. you create a circular loop), you just want each map to dump to cout, right ?

Comment: Right, I can do `nfaIt->second->tr.size()` and it will give me how many elements are in the vector but I can't figure out how to print the labels field inside the NFANode objects inside the vector.

Comment: `nfaIt->second->tr` is a map just like `nfa` is a map, so you can iterate them in exactly the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// iterate the outer map
map<string, NFANode*>::iterator nfaIt;
for (nfaIt = nfa.begin(); nfaIt != nfa.end(); ++nfaIt)
{
    // iterate each inner map
    map<string,vector<NFANode*> >::iterator trIt;
    for (trIt = nfaIt->second->tr.begin(); trIt != nfaIt->second->tr.end(); ++trIt)
    {
        // iterate each vector in the inner map
        vector<NFANode*>::iterator vecIt;
        for (vecIt = trIt->second.begin(); vecIt != trIt->second.end(); ++vecIt)
        {
            NFANode* pNodeInVecInMapInMap = *vecIt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked, thank you very much. Just for clarification, are you dereferencing with `*vecIt`? I didn't think that you had to use iterators with vectors?

Comment: You don't have to, you can treat it like an array if you like - I just liked the symmetry :)